# Azure Storage Emulator - How to specify hierarchical path?

Tags: azure, emulation, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0 and VS 2013.

How can I upload a file from a dev box and specify the hierarchical path on Azure Blob storage?

I'm developing locally with VS 2013 & Azure Storage Emulator 4.1.0.0.
I'd like to upload a file but specify the Blob's hierarchical path to the file.

```
const string ImageToUpload = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AzureCloudService1\DataBlobStorage1\HelloWorld2.png"; 
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(ImageToUpload);
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(ImageToUpload, FileMode.Open).ConfigureAwait(configureawait);
```

This code does upload the file, but winds up storing the source's physical path to the file. How do I specify to Azure Blob storage the desired hierarchical path?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... GetBlockBlobReference is what sets the blob name, and it can be named as desired. The actual file can be read into a fileStream from some other physical location and uploaded into the blob, like so:

```
    string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Clients/Clientname/" + "HelloWorld.png");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(@"Clients\ClientName");
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you want the path to be `AzureCloudService1\DataBlobStorage1\HelloWorld2.png` in your container, this is what you would have to do:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("AzureCloudService1/DataBlobStorage1/HelloWorld2.png");
```

Comment: Gaurav's answer is correct, but please note that "AzureCloudService1/DataBlobStorage1/HelloWorld2.png" is actually a blob name, there isn't real directory structure inside Azure Blob Service. Only two layers exist in hierarchy of Azure Blob Service: container & blob.

Comment: Gaurav, thanks but what I need is for the source hierarchical path to differ from the name that I want it to have within the container. For example, on my development PC that is running the Azure Storage emulator, the file might reside in the project's "App_Data\Clients\ClientName" folder. If I provide C# a physical path in order for it to read the file, then that physical path (C:\...) winds up being prepended to the blob name. I want to name the blob something different (and valid).